# Manipulating divergent series for practical applications

Tags: divergent-series, applications

I have a series summation of the form

$$
\tag{1}
S(x) = \sum_{i = -\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^{i}\left[\Phi\left(2ix\right) - \Phi\left((2i-2)x\right)\right],
$$
where $\Phi(.)$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function. We can rewrite (1) as

$$
\tag{2}
S(x) = 2\Phi(0) + \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i}\left[\Phi\left(2ix\right) + \Phi\left(-2ix\right)\right],
$$
which transforms into

$$
S(x) = 1 + \left(-2+2-2+2-2\dots\right),
$$
which obviously is bounded but divergent.

But another way to write $S(x)$ is

$$
\tag{3}
S(x) = \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i \in [-M,M]} (-1)^{i}\left[\Phi\left(2ix\right) - \Phi\left((2i-2)x\right)\right].
$$

I know that it is mathematically incorrect (even blasphemous) to suggest that $-\infty = (-1)\times \infty$, but since the summation limits are from $-M$ to $M$, it intuitively seems correct to assume that the summation limits are symmetric over the origin. As long as the summation limits are symmetric, $S(x)$ becomes

$$
\tag{4}
S(x) = 2\Phi(0)- \lim_{M\rightarrow -\infty} \Phi((2M-2)x),
$$
which is 1.

I was suggested to explore Cesaro Summation. Since all iterations are equal to 0 in the way the summation is written, it seems that I can claim $S(x)=1$.

However, I know that life is not so easy. So, my main question is what kind of logical (or mathematical) fallacy I commit here? Also, where is the logical fallacy? Is it in the transition from (1) to (3) or in the evaluation process in (4)?

My final question is, from an applied mathematics perspective, can I assume that $S(x)=1$? If I can, what is the justification?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "From an applied mathematics perspective": it depends upon your specific application. Applied mathematics are not less rigorous than more abstract mathematics. If $S(x)=1$ is correct for your application, this should be reflected into the model, i.e. $S(x)$ should be rigorously $1$. So, if you can explain your context, that would help.

Comment: Well, the sum is one for all practical purposes. The overall result, which uses the aforementioned sum at one step is verified by Monte Carlo simulations as well. However, reviewers usually raise questions with such assumptions, even though from an engineering point of view, it is unimportant. This is why I want to have the most "canon" explanation for it, rather than "it works, okay?" :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an unnecessary step "We can rewrite (1) as..." which only complicate things. Series (1) converges absolutely for any $x\in \mathbb R$ and, therefore, can be summed up to the same value $S(x)$
rearranging the terms in any order. So indeed (3) holds.

Comment: Great, but still (1) and (3) should be the same series, right? So how can one absolutely converge but the other diverge?

Comment: @C.Koca (1)and (3) are the same series and converge absolutely.  To compare it with (2): series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(1-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n(1-1)=0$ converges absolutely, but if to separate summands in the term, series $1-1+1-1+\ldots$ diverges.

Comment: Wiki says "[Rearrangements do not change the value of the sum.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence)" for absolutely convergent series.

Comment: @C.Koca rearranging terms as a whole, that's why (3) gives the sum of (1). But dividing terms into parts and rearranging those parts can change the series sum or make a  divergent series as the example in the previous comment shows.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? I really don't understand your point.

Comment: @C.Koca In (2) the term $\left[\Phi\left(2ix\right) - \Phi\left((2i-2)x\right)\right]$ is divided into parts and those parts are rearranged which leads to divergent series as dividing the term $(1-1)$ into parts 1and -1 leads to a divergent series in the example above.

Comment: My point is that series can be absolutely convergent as long as rearrangements do not change the sum. So, how is it that (1) and (3) refer to the same series and one being absolutely convergent and one being divergent?

Comment: @C.Koca (3) is the same as (1).  The problem arises then  considering (2) which is divergent, but this is due to dividing terms  into parts and rearranging them. If to drop (2), no problem and no need for summing divergent series.

Comment: Can you give me another example that is actually convergent when it is of the form $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_n$ but divergent when it is of the form $a_0+\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n+a_{-n}$, along with a discussion saying it is so?

Comment: @C.Koca In this case  $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (a_n+a_{-n})=\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i}\left[\Phi\left(2ix\right) - \Phi\left((2i-2)x\right)+\Phi\left(-2ix\right) - \Phi\left(-(2i+2)x\right)\right].$$

Comment: This is not another example. This is the example in the question.

Comment: If $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  a_n$ as absolutely convergent then  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+a_{-n})$ is also absolutely convergent.  But the four term sum above is not (2), so I still don't see the problem.

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you provide some source about rearrangement? To back your claim that mixing terms is not considered rearrangement. Otherwise, your answer is wrong.

Comment: @C.Koca I don't quite understand. Do you mean mixing as putting $b_n=a_n+b_{-n}$ or something else?

Comment: Yes. When I think of rearranging, it is not just changing the order, it is changing the summands too as long as the overall series remain the same. So, I need a source that has a definition of rearranging. Otherwise, the series I refer to cannot be absolutely convergent.

Comment: @C.Koca The definition of rearrangement is just changing the order, e.g. in W. Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, 1976, p.75.

Comment: Can you post an SS?

Comment: @C.Koca Sorry, what is SS?

Comment: Btw for real $x$ the sum of (1) $S(x)\equiv0$.